# ISAKMP negotiation error connecting to VPN from China?

Tags: networking, vpn

I am attempting to connect through SonicWall Global VPN Client. It comes up with the following error much of the time when trying to connect:

"The peer is not responding to phase 1 ISAKMP requests. 
Starting ISAKMP phase 1 negotiation. 
An error occurred."

Does anyone have any idea why this occurs and how this can be fixed?

Comment: I had the same error with the Dell GVC Software (Version 4_9.) The older SonicwallClient works stable on Windows 8.1 .
Now I'm using 4.7.3.0403 here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISAKMP may use a too high MTU causing a split of it. Try lowering your LAN MTU or the MTU on the client system.

Also, check if NAT is done correctly and if the correct ports are open.